# how do i parse inputstream to document builder?

Tags: java, android, xmlhttprequest

I am making an android app, and i am making an httprequest to get an XML document, my httpEntity does not return null, and i am trying to use the documentbuilderfactory to parse the file and get the data i need from the xml.

I have:

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(URL);
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", getAuthHeader());

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();   

        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

at this point i get an error exception that looks like this

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected: /hr read: body (position:END_TAG @10:8 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40564d70)
```

Has anyone seen this or know what i am doing i cannot find what the problem is, if this is not enough code i can provide more, not much more is being done, just the http request.
the "XML" file that i am trying to get looks like this

```
<ads>
  <ad>
    <id>6</id>
    <minViews>10</minViews>
    <duration>4</duration>
    <actionUrl>URL</actionUrl>
    <imageUrl>URL</imageUrl>
    <impressionCount>0</impressionCount>
  </ad>
<ads>
```

and that is all that is in the file. and i am trying to get the URL in both spots.

Comment: When you say parse the file, what are you trying to get out of it, a string? a node?

Comment: Seems like the fetched XML is syntactically incorrect

Comment: I'd recommend reading and printing out the response content as a `String` to see what you're actually getting... I'm guessing it's not what you think you should be getting.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the document is an HTML which is not XML-compliant. The unterminated `<hr>` tag is a dead giveaway. XML parsing is simply not applicable for those documents.

Depending on what do you want from that document, you might wanna roll your own parser, find and adapt an existing one, or use a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

DTD are missing to your xml , add the correct doctype and your parsing will be fine .